# IPhone 6 Vuforia ImageTarget model rendering

Tags: unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, vuforia

I have been developing an AR application using Vuforia ImageTarget, which run very well on Android, Iphone devices except IPhone 6 (This only happen on IPhone6 device). 
Please take a look at the image, I have searched on Vuforia developer forum & can't find solution.

Unity 5.3.1f 
Vuforia 5.5.9

[image: render err 01]

[image: render err 02]

Comment: You should be able to set Metal as API with the latest Vuforia release. Is it on?

Comment: What kind of textures are you using? Did you set your textures for mobile?

Comment: @firativerson: I haven't noticed there was an option like that, I'll try. Thanks you.